# Radio button issue with same name in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, radio-button, radio-group

This problem worked fine before ExtJS 6.0.
I started having this problem after upgrading from ExtJS 6.0 to ExtJS 6.2.

1. I created two form panels in ExtJS.
2. After adding radio buttons to each panel, set the same name.
3. Although the names are the same, I expected each panel to be isolated so they wouldn't affect each other.
4. However, there is a problem when checking the changed data with dirty because the radio buttons affect each other.

I want to know why the 6.0 and 6.2 versions behave differently.
The same problem is confirmed in 7.6.
You can check each version in the Fiddle link below.

ExtJS Fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3nn6

**ExtJS 6.0**
[ExtJS 6.0 Radio Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SfAj.png)

**ExtJS 6.2**
[ExtJS 6.2 Radio Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQd2b.png)

I tried this.

1. I used the "local" property of the radio button, but it didn't work.
2. I couldn't find a solution, and I'm using a different name.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure your radio button to allow the other component to share the same name. hope [this](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-shareableName) helps

{xtype: 'radiofield', shareableName: true}

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your answer directly. Use links purely as references since their content can change or the link can break.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want the radio buttons in each panel to be isolated.

I tried setting shareableName: false but there is still a problem.